# Printer does not work

Tags: printer

My printer is a Canon iSensys MF4010. Once connected elementary automatically installed its driver and informed me it's ready. I clicked on the info icon in the printer settings and in the drop down there is a "print test page" button, once clicking on it nothing happens. I then created a doc in libre office and tried to print it, it does nothing either. It's not even listed as a print job. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you try to print a libreoffice document, do you see and can select that printer? ~ I have never been able to print in Linux without installing drivers separately, most likely the "automatic installation" is deceptive. ~ You should post this on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), most if not all printer issues are ubuntu and not elementary-specific, and there you have better chances to get assistance.

Comment: Yes the printer was selected. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on Canon's website link to drivers for your printer:
[Drivers](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf4010.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=)
Just select Linux 64bit and download. ;)

Comment: I have not thought about this. I thought Canon won't have a linux driver!

Comment: :D You see! Canon supports professionals ;)

Comment: Yet, I could not switch because they don't support home recording musicians. I could not make my VSTs work.

Comment: I've no Canon Pixma G2012 and they don't have a linux driver :(